# Anchor tag issue: hide browser displayed link using css

Tags: html, css

Please refer to below screenshot

[image]

I want to hide the grey link that is displayed by the browser by using css without having to remove the href on the anchor tag.

How can this be done?

Comment: it's the browser's status bar and you can't mod browser's defaults.

Comment: You cannot do that and even if you can, don't do it, it's a bad practice and is insecure for the user browsing your website.

Comment: As stated above you can't. Read for example: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/FtD7qjochgw